# как скопировать текст в js

Tags: javascript

и так, я пишу скрипт для [novoline](https://novoline.wtf/) и мне нужно скопировать текст в буфер обмена, без использования web функции, тк document и `navigator.clipboard.writeText(All)` не работают((

```
module = script.registerModule("CopyUserInfo",MISC);

module.onEvent("enable",function(){
    var All = "Username: " + player.getName() + "; VERSION - " + client.getVersion()
    client.toggleModule("CopyUserInfo")
})
```

Comment: и ссылку на guide тоже добавляй

Comment: https://novoline.gitbook.io/novoscript/ @Grundy

Comment: В сам вопрос.  Добавь эту ссылку. В документации не видно ничего похожего на работу с clipboard. Либо этого нельзя сделать, либо какая-то недокументированная особенность. Где ты проверяешь работоспособность скрипта?

Comment: https://novoline.wtf/ @Grundy какие вообще есть в js способы копирования в clipboard

Comment: обрати внимание, что ты используешь не javascript. Поэтому то, что работает в браузере либо в nodejs может не работать в твоей среде. Сам по себе js не предоставляет никаких способов работы с окружением вроде clipboard

Comment: По твоей ссылке я вижу только три видео и какие-то списки ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: это клиент для игры. там есть система скриптов, я кинул сайт этого клиента @Grundy

Comment: так как нет ни документации, ни возможности проверить скрипт, похоже все это тебе самому придется делать :)